# 3gp file streaming server in Fedora

Tags: amazon-ec2, streaming, video-streaming, fedora

I want to set up a streaming server to stream 3gp videos on-demand. I've tried using ffmpeg, but it seems ffmpeg doesn't support 3gp streaming. It gives an error saying

`Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but container format requires global headers`

The log: http://pastebin.com/S8p97Qt5 and the config file: http://pastebin.com/cbGnkEed

Is there any streaming server for 3gp file streaming that works well in a Fedora 14 EC2 instance?
Any suggestions?

Or, is there a way to make ffmpeg work for 3gp file streaming? I can live stream in 3gp format using ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Open Streaming Server](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openstreaming/) seems to do it.

Comment: Is that still maintained? The last update was in August 2009

Comment: I didn't use this. But this is the best answer I could get.